# Adding a constant value to columns in a Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark data frame which will be like below

```
id person age
1  naveen 24
```

I want add a constant "del" to each column value except the last column in the dataframe like below,

```
id   person   age
1del naveendel 24
```

Can someone assist me how to implement this in Spark df using Scala

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `lit` and `concat` functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// add suffix to all but last column (would work for any number of cols):
val colsWithSuffix = df.columns.dropRight(1).map(c => concat(col(c), lit("del")) as c)
def result = df.select(colsWithSuffix :+ $"age": _*)

result.show()
// +----+---------+---+
// |id  |person   |age|
// +----+---------+---+
// |1del|naveendel|24 |
// +----+---------+---+
```

**EDIT**: to also accommodate null values, you can wrap the column with `coalesce` before appending the suffix - replace the like calculating `colsWithSuffix` with:

```
val colsWithSuffix = df.columns.dropRight(1)
  .map(c => concat(coalesce(col(c), lit("")), lit("del")) as c)
```

Comment: This works perfectly when all the columns have values. suppose if I have a null value for a column. Is it possible to make it as "del" ?

Comment: Edited the answer with a suggestion to solve this too

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day :)